# Ограничение символов

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, взгляните на эти строки:

```
$('#messege_twit').keyup(function () {
    $('#messege_dlina').text($('#messege_twit').attr('value').length);
```

они подсчитывают количество символов в текстовом поле и выводят кол-во символов. Задача такая, нужно чтоб при наборе 100 символов, цифра количества символов подкрашивалась красным, чтоб человек знал, что он набрал больше чем нужно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

я бы сделал так:

`var text_len = $('message_twit'); 
  if(text_len.attr('value').length>100) {
    text_len.css('color', 'red');
}`